# Adding fallback for functionality related to CSS3 animation completion

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I am using CSS3 animations provided by [animate css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) library. There are places like loading screen that fades out loading animation and waits for this animation to be complete in order to perform additional actions. So:

```
var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';

  $('#loading')
    .addClass('fadeOut')
    .one(animationEnd, function() {
      $(this).css('display', 'none');
    })
```

So if browser doesn't support CSS3 animation related to fadeOut class, will it not perform the function on animation end? What could be the fallback here in order to fire this function.

Comment: As far as I know, the `animationEnd` event won't fire if the browser doesn't support animations. Your best bet would probably be to detect if the browser supports animation (Modernizer?) and if it doesn't then do the same operation as done within the `animationEnd` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Will animation end event be fired if browser doesn't support CSS animations?**

Generally if the browser does not support CSS3 animations then the `animationEnd` event would also not be fired and so the callback function which gets executed upon completion of animation will not be called at all.

**What is the solution to execute the callback function?**

One way to make sure that the callback function gets executed even on browsers that do not support CSS3 animations would be to test for animation support and (a) execute the callback function after the completion of animation if it is supported or (b) execute callback function immediately if animation isn't supported.

In the below snippet, I have used the code provided by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Detecting_CSS_animation_support) to test for animation support. In browsers that support animation, the below snippet would produce the shake effect and at the end of it change background color to red whereas in browsers that don't support animations, it will change background color to red immediately.

This has been tested in IE9 (doesn't support CSS3 animation), IE10, IE11, Edge, Mozilla and Chrome. In Opera, the code works when tested separately in a Fiddle or CodePen but the color doesn't change after animation in the snippet here. I assume that this must be something to do with Stack Snippet and not the code itself.

```js
/* Code from MDN */

var animation = false,
  animationstring = 'animation',
  keyframeprefix = '',
  domPrefixes = 'Webkit Moz O ms Khtml'.split(' '),
  pfx = '',
  elm = document.createElement('div');

if (elm.style.animationName !== undefined) {
  animation = true;
}

if (animation === false) {
  for (var i = 0; i < domPrefixes.length; i++) {
    if (elm.style[domPrefixes[i] + 'AnimationName'] !== undefined) {
      pfx = domPrefixes[i];
      animationstring = pfx + 'Animation';
      keyframeprefix = '-' + pfx.toLowerCase() + '-';
      animation = true;
      break;
    }
  }
}

/* End of Code from MDN */

if (animation) { // check if animation is supported
  var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
  $('.animated-element').one(animationEnd, function() { // if supported attach animationEnd handler
    callback();
  })
} else { // if animation is not supported execute callback immediately
  callback();
}

function callback() {
  console.log('Hello World!');
  $('.animated-element').css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

```css
.animated-element {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  animation: shake 1s 2s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes shake {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(10px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(-10px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(10px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(-10px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='animated-element'>Hello!</div>
```

**Are there any libraries which can be used to perform these tests?**

You can use libraries like Modernizr to test for animation support and then decide the further course of actions based on it.